# Is there a way to limit the number of CPU cores Bazel uses?

Tags: cpu-cores, bazel

Is there a way to tell Bazel when building how many CPU cores it can use?

### TL;DR

I build TensorFlow on a VMware Workstation and being a virtual machine I can adjust the number of processors and cores for the virtual machine.

In the process of building TensorFlow I found that using only one core works.
When I give the Workstation four cores and build TensorFlow it eventually halts the system to the point I have to reboot.

If I wait a few hours (leave it alone overnight) it sometimes returns with the following error:

> gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

While I can change the number of cores using the virtual machines configuration options I would prefer to do it without having to shut down and restart the virtual machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Bazel User Manual](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html)

> [--local_resources](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--local_resources) availableRAM,**availableCPU**,availableIO
>
> This option, which takes three comma-separated floating point
>   arguments, specifies the amount of local resources that Bazel can take
>   into consideration when scheduling build and test activities. Option
>   expects amount of available RAM (in MB), **number of CPU cores** (with 1.0
>   representing single full core) and workstation I/O capability (with
>   1.0 representing average workstation). By default Bazel will estimate amount of RAM and number of CPU cores directly from system
>   configuration and will assume 1.0 I/O resource.
>
> If this option is used, Bazel will ignore both
>   --ram_utilization_factor.

Comment: This does allow one to reduce the resources used, but not as I would expect.  After struggling to make sense, I closed other applications and tested with different settings.  It seems Bazel consumes approximately double the number of cores I set and sometimes consumes all cores for many seconds.  Even with `bazel test -c opt --local_resources 20000,1,0.25` I see significant load on my system.

Comment: I was going to fix the broken link above to point to https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--local_resources but the text isn't the same as what used to be in the user manual. I'm not sure what the best approach here would be...

Comment: @MattPassell Since I view this all as Creative Content and it is here to help others, and I haven't touched Tensorflow in some time, take your pick. 1) Edit this question for what needs to be changed. 2) Add your own answer.  3) Edit this question, but add a new section leaving in the original answer and noting what you would consider a correct answer.

Comment: Fair enough. :) I'll try to come back to this.

Answer (score 28):

some examples for your .bazelrc

```
build --local_ram_resources=HOST_RAM*.5 --local_cpu_resources=HOST_CPUS-1 (leave one core free)
```

or

```
build --local_cpu_resources=1 (use a single core)
```

See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html#flag--local_cpu_resources

The currently accepted answer is deprecated.

Comment: yes, the current accepted answer is deprecated and this one worked