# How do I specify the number of CPU cores bazel uses?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I am building syntaxnet (tensorflow fork) with bazel. It's working *very* slowly and keeps hanging up.

The last time I had this problem (with caffe) someone told me to change the number of cores I was using by adding `-j4`. In bazel this command did not work. Any custom command for bazel like this?

CPU Specs: 3.8ghz clock, Quadcore

CPU Model: AMD 4800(or something along those lines).

Comment: it should use all cores by default. IE, I'm running it on 12 core machine, and `top` shows 12 `clang` commands running in parallel and using all 100% CPU, that's not the case for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added `--jobs 4` and it managed to get through.  It's probably the same as `-j4`.

Complete command line was:

```
bazel test --jobs 4 --genrule_strategy=standalone syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
```

Comment: aah okay. Much better than --local_resources!!

Comment: Note that, according to https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/bazel-user-manual.html  the default jobs value is 200.  That acts as an upper bound for bazel, and it tries to work out what parallelism is possible based on memory, cpu count, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As [Guy Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243762/guy-coder) describes in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34766939/527489) to a similar question, try `--local_resources`.  In my limited experience, it seems that Bazel consumes approximately double the number of cores I set and sometimes consumes all cores for many seconds. Even with `bazel test -c opt --local_resources 20000,1,0.25` I see significant load on my system.  (Following is his answer)

From [Bazel User Manual](http://bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html)

> [--local_resources](http://bazel.io/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--local_resources) availableRAM,**availableCPU**,availableIO
>
> This option, which takes three comma-separated floating point
>   arguments, specifies the amount of local resources that Bazel can take
>   into consideration when scheduling build and test activities. Option
>   expects amount of available RAM (in MB), **number of CPU cores** (with 1.0
>   representing single full core) and workstation I/O capability (with
>   1.0 representing average workstation). By default Bazel will estimate amount of RAM and number of CPU cores directly from system
>   configuration and will assume 1.0 I/O resource.
>
> If this option is used, Bazel will ignore both
>   --ram_utilization_factor.